# what does it mean select="cos2 9" in plot() in R?

Tags: r, plot

I have the following piece of code for a R plot:

```
plot(res,cex=0.9,shadow=F,habillage=10,invisible=c("ind.sup","quali"),select="cos2 9",unselect=1)
```

I would like to know what the argument `select="cos2 9"` means?

Comment: You need to provide more context to your question. `plot` is an incredibly generic function, which forwards most of its arguments via `...`. `select` and `unselect` are not standard arguments, as far as I am aware, so I'm guessing that either (a) `res` is some non-base class using custom S3 method dispatch (`plot.strange_class`); or (b) this is poorly written code that doesn't actually work. Either way, provide a **complete, reproducible example**.

Comment: res<- PCA(d,quali.sup<- c(1,10))  and d is my data . l want to know what does select ="cos2 9"  means ? the function and utility of cos2

Answer (score 2):

`select` lets you choose which elements to include.  [plot.PCA](http://www.inside-r.org/packages/cran/FactoMineR/docs/plot.PCA) gives a brief overview of the options with the `select` statement in the Details section.  [This link](http://www.sthda.com/english/wiki/factominer-and-factoextra-principal-component-analysis-visualization-r-software-and-data-mining#cos2-quality-of-variables-on-the-factor-map) explains those options a little bit further.  Cos2 is "The quality of representation of the variables of the principal components are called the cos2.", meaning how much of a variable is represented in a given component.

Example biplot from google:

[image]

This would show that variables `Cond` and `Ca` would have large Cos2 values, since they represent more of the first component.  `Fecal` would have a smaller Cos2 value and `Do and TSS` would both be very close to zero.

Similarly for the second principal component, we see the most representation from the variables `TSS` and `DO`, so those would have larger Cos2 values for the second component.

Comment: cos2 is "quality of representation "  quality according to what  ? and why we need cos2 ?

Comment: edited, hope its a little bit more informative.  Essentially it measures how much a variable is represented in a component.

Comment: Nice answer, especially considering the lack of information provided in the question.

Comment: Thank you a lot all of you , it's really helping me